# ExtJS 5 Grid Widget Column with Multiple xtypes

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a data object like this:

```
data = [
    {text: 'What is your name?', xtype: 'textfield'},
    {text: 'What is your favorite number?', xtype: 'numberfield'}
]
```

I need a grid to show each of the data objects in their own row. That row should contain a form field of the xtype provided.

Implementing this was easy in ExtJS 4 using this plugin : http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column.

With this plugin, a developer could just specify a "renderer" function on the column config that returns a config object for any arbitrary component and that component would then be rendered in the cell. Unfortunately, this plugin will not work for ExtJS 5.

ExtJS 5 seemed to promise to fix the need for this plugin with its new "Widget Column" functionality so I was eagerly awaiting its release but when it finally came out, it did not live up to the hype. It seems to require that every single row have the same exact component with only the value different. There seemed to be no way for one row of the Widget Column to have a textfield and the next row having a numberfield.

Am I correct in my conclusion that the new ExtJS 5 "Widget Column" functionality is too limited and will not work for my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with a project of mine. Unfortunately renderer is not an option yet for widgetcolumns. Extjs 5.0.1 is said to be releasing soon, and they claim this will fix many of the bugs that exist in Extjs 5 so I hope this is included in the fix. Until then I would suggest using the component column plugin you referenced. It works fine for Extjs 5 as long as you replace

```
return this.lastFrameWidth = parentDiv.getFrameWidth('lr') + parentTd.getFrameWidth('lr');
```

with

```
return this.lastFrameWidth = parentDiv.getBorderWidth('lr') + parentDiv.getPadding('lr') + parentTd.getBorderWidth('lr') + parentTd.getPadding('lr');
```

[Source](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148064-Component-Column-Components-in-Grid-Cells/page17#165).

One of the parameters for renderer is the record and row number for where the component exists when it is `rendered` and can be saved in a custom attribute to be used in later events such as `change`.